# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Tags: html, redux

файл index.js

```
import {createStore } from 'redux';

function audios(state = [], action){
  if (action.type === 'AddCanal'){
    return[
      ...state,
      action.payload
    ];
  }
  return state;
}

const store = createStore(audios);

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log('subscribe', store.getState());
  const list = document.querySelectorAll('.list')[0];
  store.getState().forEach(audio => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = audio;
    list.appendChild(li);
  });
})

const addBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.add')[0];
addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const audioName = document.querySelectorAll('.audioInput')[0].value;
  console.log('audioName', audioName);
  store.dispatch({type: 'AddCanal', payload: audioName});
});
```

файл index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8"/>
        <title>Radio Boss</title>
        <!-- <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href = "./stylesheets/styleLogin.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/main.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/profile.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/help.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/edit.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/user.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/add.css" /> -->
    </head>
    <body>
      <input type="text" className="audioInput" />
      <button className="add">Сохранить</button>
      <ul className="list">
        <li></li>
      </ul>
        <div id="form"></div>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="./build/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Можно ваш `html` код то же увидеть?

Comment: добавила index.html

Comment: @Grundy здесь ошибка совсем другое, там человек берет все элементы с классом и хочет прикрепить обработчик события на `array`.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, да, я уже увидел, что конкретный элемент берется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы написали `<button className="add">Сохранить</button>` а должно быть `<button class="add">Сохранить</button>`.
Вот пример кода, и оно работает:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8"/>
        <title>Radio Boss</title>
        <!-- <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href = "./stylesheets/styleLogin.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/main.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/profile.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/help.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/edit.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/user.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/add.css" /> -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/babel">
            const addBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.add')[0];
            addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log('clicked');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" className="audioInput" />
        <button class="add">Сохранить</button>
        <ul className="list">
            <li></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="form"></div>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="./build/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Я просто здесь поменял обработчик клика и добавил в нем `console.log` что бы здесь увидели работу кода.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает))

Comment: @Zhanelya не за что

Comment: @Zhanelya А вы птичку забыли)))))